# struct.unpack not returning strings

Tags: python, struct

Here is my code (py3.1):

```
def get_string(self,chars):
    return struct.unpack("{}s".format(chars),self.get_bin(chars))
```

`b'MESH'` is going in, `(b'MESH',)` is coming out. Why am I not getting a string?

Comment: If you want to turn `bytes` into into a `str`, you are doing it wrong(tm). `struct` is for dealing with tightly-laid-out binary(!) data.

Comment: That's what I'm dealing with. MESH etc. are just labels among the binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps when asking questions if you make sure that the code is actually what you did run. What you show would have given an error. Also ensure that the code snippet includes all information so that people don't need to guess.

```
>>> chars = "MESH" # guess
>>> binchars = b"MESH" # guess
>>> struct_fmt = "{}s".format(chars) # what you showed
>>> struct_fmt
'MESHs' ############### won't work
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack(struct_fmt, binchars)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: bad char in struct format ############ didn't work
>>> struct_fmt2 = "{}s".format(len(chars)) # what you probably did use
>>> struct_fmt2
'4s' #### looks much better
>>> struct.unpack(struct_fmt2, binchars)
(b'MESH',) ### did work
>>>
```

As the manual says, "For unpacking, the resulting bytes object ..."

Comment: I did post my code and it does work, thank you. `chars` is the number of chars in the desired string, not the string itself like you "guessed". (It does look like you answered the question though. So I forgive you.)

Comment: chars is not an appropriate name for an integer, the format (`{}`) gave no clue at all. You didn't show the WHOLE code (`self.get_bin(chars)` ???) so that somebody could reproduce what you were doing. In fact, all you needed to show to demonstrate what you meant was `struct.unpack("4s", b"MESH")`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
return struct.unpack("{}s".format(chars),self.get_bin(chars))[0].decode('ASCII')
```

But does not explain why `unpack()` neglects to do this itself. I'll leave the question open until that's answered.

Edit: Jason's improvement:

```
return self.get_bin(chars).decode('ASCII')
```

Makes a mockery of struct really...

Comment: I'm confused... Why would you expect `struct` to decode a string?? And even if `struct` would be expected to do this, how would `struct.unpack` be able to automatically infer whether the string is ASCII or UTF8 or some other type of unicode?

Comment: `10s > char[10]` and `10w > wchar_t[10]`? I'm assuming there is actually a way, as it does *claim* to do string.

Comment: "makes a mockery": well of course if that's all you have, you don't don't need `struct` ... `struct` is for structures that might require a format like "<4s2H2Bd"

Answer (score 0):

unpack returns a tuple, a tuple of length 1 in this case.

Add

[0]

to the end of what you have and it should give what you expect.